# Gstreamer 1.0 ios sdk installer failed to install

Tags: ios, gstreamer

This is my first time trying with Gstreamer for ios , I went with the tutorial and installed the SDK with the link provided by the tutorial: 
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+iOS+development

The installation works fine, but after I start trying the tutorial example projects, there couple of compiling errors compiling about missing gst/video/videooverlay.h . Then I looked into the header folder under the installed GStreamer header folder, there is no filed called video/videooverlay.h
Then I search online, found this information:
Gstreamer for iOS provided is out of date. I used the freedesktop packages

from https://github.com/braincorp/gstreamer_ios_tutorial

Then I downloaded another installation pkg for GStreamer

Then while I was trying to install the later version, the installer give me error saying: 
you cannot install GStreamer 1.0 (Development Files) in this location.

Then I thought I might need to uninstall the previous version, but I couldn't finder a standard uninstallation option from the installer, then I searched online, find one post suggest remove the GStreamer folder under ~/Library/Developer

I have removed the installed folder, so I don't have any header files, but the new installer still gives the same error

I have been trying to figure this out for sometime, couldn't find useful info on line , I really appreicate any clue and help you might have!

Thanks!!
Jing

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here..
not sure what's the issue, after restarting my mac, and run the installer couple of times with the same error, it suddenly worked ....... i am not sure what's the matter here, hope gstreamer team can improve the stability of the installer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

At work we are currently trying to get the IOS tutorials from the streamer 1.0 sdk to run.


1) Compilation: 
Same thing: we managed to bootstrap (cerbero ... bootstrap) and compile (cerebra ... package streamer-sdk) using the official cerebero git repository.

But:
a) We had to mock around with the /cerbero/cerbero/enums.py file: 
Add in the collection of supported old IOS (6.0, 6.1, 7.0, etc...) the one corresponding to our Xcode version : IOS 8.4
b) We had to customize the /cerbero/config/ios.config and iOS-universal.config files to get them to use the right architecture in our case: arm7v or arm7 instead of X64_86 or x86
c) We removed the not found is_asm() function from the x264 plugin's recipe file in the /cerbero/recipes.
For a reason we ignore, for all other platforms but IOS, the recipes check on the architecture available using: 
if self.config.target_arch == Architecture.xxx:
of iOS is was using that missing function: is_asm(self.config.target_arch)

We replaced it by:
if self.config.target_arch == Architecture.ARMv7:

Compiling an iOS app using streamer:
So far it is a failure. we bumped into the same missing overlay.h header file. We couldn't find it anywhere.

**DIFFERENCE** between **gstreamer.com** (the sdk provider) and the **official streamer website (free desktop.gsteamer.org)**:

We found out that gstreamer.com is clearly a commercial goal company that is making available the sdk, that people struggle on with for IOS (tested and working fine on linux) and the official website is providing the gstreamer library only without an sdk.

So this is what we are trying to use instead as of today.

**Versions infos**:
sdk (from gstreamer.com): current cerbero git master branch: git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-sdk/cerbero

official gstreamer library:
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.5.2/